# Selenium Find By Xpath returning the wrong element

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, xquery

I am trying to select a channel from a series of channles that are displayed in a HTML table. I'm using the following Selenium method to select the link

`WebElement channel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),Sales)]"));
channel.click();`

However it's selecting the first channel in the list (Account Management) instead. I would expect that it would either select the correct channel or throw an error, rather than select the wrong one. The following is the full xpath of the channel I want:

`/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/ul/li[2]/a/span`

The list of channels is defined like this in the HTML code:

```
<form action="nextpage.do" method="post" name="selectChannelForm">
<div class="de">
    <h2>Select channel</h2>
    <table id="selectChannelForm">
        <tbody id=""></tbody>
        <tbody id="">
            <tr rowtype="container">
            <td class="desecond" colspan="3">
                <ul>    
                <li>
                    <a id="selected_a" href="nextpage.do?selectedChannel=123">
                    <span>Account Management</span></a>
                </li>   
                <li>
                    <a id="selected_a" href="nextpage.do?selectedChannel=456">
                    <span>Sales</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="selected_a" href="nextpage.do?selectedChannel=789">
                    <span>Complaints</span></a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" value="selectChannelForm" name="formid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath that you are using is missing quotes `""` around `Sales` text. `text()` function takes an argument that is a string and a string can be formed using quotes. Update your xpath in the following way -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales')]")).click();
```

Or if you want to assign it to a WebElement, then do put in your quotes -

```
WebElement channel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales')]"));
channel.click();
```

If at all you want to write nested double quotes or nested single quotes then use an escape character `\` to write it. Here's how -

```
WebElement channel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),\"Sales\")]"));
channel.click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow I feel very stupid now! I think looking at it for so long made me miss the obvious. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## First - your mistake!

You forgot the quotation marks around "Sales", just change your code a bit and it will work:

```
WebElement channel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales')]"));
channel.click();
```

## Second - xpath bug?

You're right that it is weird, that you are not getting an error message but instead the first element that is a span.
This might acutally be a bug in xpath. The contains functions realizes that your second argument is no a string, but instead of returning **false**, it returns **true**.

It actually hits all three of the span items. You only get the first as a result because you used the `findElement` function.

Try this and you will see the quirk:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),Sales)]")).size());
```

Result will be:

> 3

## Third - might be "as designed"

Having a look at the [w3c definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains) you will find the following line:

> If the value of $arg2 is the zero-length string, then the function
>   returns true.

Then on the [xpath-site of microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924018.aspx) you will find another interesting hint to the puzzle:

> If an argument is not of type string, it is first converted to a
>   string and then evaluated.

Putting all this information together, I guess, xpath interprets your non-string/non-variable second parameter as an empty string and therefore returns true for all span elements since you were searching for `//span`.

## UPDATE

From @MichaelKay in the comments we learn, that my "guess" was pretty close:

> In XPath and XQuery, a bare name like "hello" means child::hello, and
>   if you're not using schema-awareness, then the system will just look
>   for children called hello, and if there aren't any, it will return an
>   empty node-set.

Conclusion: The behaviour the OP sees is as designed, even though it seems pretty non-intuitive.

Comment: Yes, if the second argument to contains() is an empty node-set, the answer will always be true.

Comment: @MichaelKay, yeah, still it would be interesting why here this "non-string" is interpreted as an empty node-set and is not just kind of indicating an error and thus returning false. Or better returning an exception, what usually happens when you have a character within a xquery missing.

Comment: In XPath and XQuery, a bare name like "hello" means `child::hello`, and if you're not using schema-awareness, then the system will just look for children called `hello`, and if there aren't any, it will return an empty node-set. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @MichaelKay thx! yes, I will enhance my answer with your comment, do you also have a link to the source of this information for completeness?

Answer (score 1):

The xpath need to be modified as "//span[contains(text(),'Sales')]" .

As we can see below in the method definitions, contains method will return true only If second parameter is also a text.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

contains(s1, s2) 
returns true if s1 contains s2.
text() 
finds a node of type text